# sub claim is missing Identity Server 4 with Mongo DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 with MongoDB to create an identity portal.

```
services.AddIdentityServer().AddMongoRepository()
                .AddMongoDbForAspIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(Configuration)
                .AddClients()
                .AddIdentityApiResources()
                .AddPersistedGrants()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();


app.UseMongoDbForIdentityServer();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
```

Here is the Mongo Db Repository

```
namespace IdentityServer.Extension
{
    public static class IdentityServerBuilderExtensions
    {/// <summary>
     /// Adds mongo repository (mongodb) for IdentityServer
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="builder"></param>
     /// <returns></returns>
        public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddMongoRepository(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository>();
            return builder;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds mongodb implementation for the "Asp Net Core Identity" part (saving user and roles)
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks><![CDATA[
        /// Contains implemenations for
        /// - IUserStore<T>
        /// - IRoleStore<T>
        /// ]]></remarks>
        public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddMongoDbForAspIdentity<TIdentity, TRole>(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder, IConfigurationRoot configuration) where
            TIdentity : ApplicationUser where TRole : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDB.IdentityRole
        {

            //User Mongodb for Asp.net identity in order to get users stored
            var configurationOptions = configuration.Get<MongoDbConfigurationOptions>();
            var client = new MongoClient(configurationOptions.MongoConnection);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(configurationOptions.MongoDatabaseName);

            // Configure Asp Net Core Identity / Role to use MongoDB
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserStore<TIdentity>>(x =>
            {
                var usersCollection = database.GetCollection<TIdentity>("Identity_Users");
                IndexChecks.EnsureUniqueIndexOnNormalizedEmail(usersCollection);
                IndexChecks.EnsureUniqueIndexOnNormalizedUserName(usersCollection);
                return new UserStore<TIdentity>(usersCollection);
            });

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRoleStore<TRole>>(x =>
            {
                var rolesCollection = database.GetCollection<TRole>("Identity_Roles");
                IndexChecks.EnsureUniqueIndexOnNormalizedRoleName(rolesCollection);
                return new RoleStore<TRole>(rolesCollection);
            });
            builder.Services.AddIdentity<TIdentity, TRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            return builder;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure ClientId / Secrets
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder"></param>
        /// <param name="configurationOption"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddClients(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IClientStore, CustomClientStore>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ICorsPolicyService, InMemoryCorsPolicyService>();
            return builder;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Configure API  &  Resources
        /// Note: Api's have also to be configured for clients as part of allowed scope for a given clientID 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddIdentityApiResources(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IResourceStore, CustomResourceStore>();
            return builder;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure Grants
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder">The builder.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddPersistedGrants(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IPersistedGrantStore, CustomPersistedGrantStore>();
            return builder;
        }

    }
}
```

**Account Controller**

private readonly SignInManager _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager _userManager;

```
    public AccountController(
        IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction,
        IClientStore clientStore,
        IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
        IEventService events, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _interaction = interaction;
        _clientStore = clientStore;
        _schemeProvider = schemeProvider;
        _events = events;
    }

if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password,
                    model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: true); 
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
                    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.Email, clientId: context?.ClientId));

                    // only set explicit expiration here if user chooses "remember me". 
                    // otherwise we rely upon expiration configured in cookie middleware.
                    AuthenticationProperties props = null;
                    if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
                    {
                        props = new AuthenticationProperties
                        {
                            IsPersistent = true,
                            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                        };
                    };

                    // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, user.UserName, props);

                    if (context != null)
                    {
                        if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))
                        {
                            // if the client is PKCE then we assume it's native, so this change in how to
                            // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                            return View("Redirect", new RedirectViewModel { RedirectUrl = model.ReturnUrl });
                        }

                        // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }

                    // request for a local page
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect("~/");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
                        throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
                    }
                }

                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(model.UserName, "invalid credentials", clientId:context?.ClientId));
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
            }
```

Exception when running this line of code

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password,model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

Exception Error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: sub claim is missing
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerAuthenticationService.AssertRequiredClaims(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerAuthenticationService.AugmentPrincipal(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerAuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInWithClaimsAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, IEnumerable`1 additionalClaims)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(TUser user, Boolean isPersistent, String loginProvider, Boolean bypassTwoFactor)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean lockoutOnFailure)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.PasswordSignInAsync(String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean lockoutOnFailure)
   at IdentityServer.AccountController.Login(LoginInputModel model, String button) in /Users/macbook/Projects/IdentityPortal/IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs:line 116
```

[image: added screen shot]

Answer (score 7):

First, while you are adding a client to indentityserver, you must give the client 
some allowed scopes, one of them is Profile:

```
 new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "userjs",
                    ClientName = "",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    //ClientUri= $"{clientsUrl["UserSpa"]}",
                    RedirectUris =           { $"{clientsUrl["UserSpa"]}/" },
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { $"{clientsUrl["UserSpa"]}/" },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins =     { $"{clientsUrl["UserSpa"]}" },
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {

                        "club",
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        **IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,**
                    },
                    RequireClientSecret = false
                },
```

Second, Add AddProfileService extension method after  IdentityServer to services:

```
services.AddIdentityServer().AddMongoRepository()
                .AddMongoDbForAspIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole> 
                 (Configuration)
                .AddClients()
                .AddIdentityApiResources()
                .AddPersistedGrants()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

Third, implement  IProfileService:

```
 public class ProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IServiceCollection _services;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private CalcAllowedPermissions _calcAllowedPermissions;

        public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _services = new ServiceCollection();
            var sp = _services.BuildServiceProvider();
            _userManager = userManager;
            _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            _calcAllowedPermissions = new CalcAllowedPermissions(_context);
        }
    **//This method is called whenever claims about the user are requested (e.g. during token creation or via the userinfo endpoint)**
        public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var subject = context.Subject ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context.Subject));

            var subjectId = subject.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "sub").FirstOrDefault().Value;

            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(subjectId);
            if (user == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid subject identifier");

            var claims = GetClaimsFromUser(user,subject);
            context.IssuedClaims = claims.Result.ToList();
        }

        public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            var subject = context.Subject ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context.Subject));

            var subjectId = subject.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "sub").FirstOrDefault().Value;
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(subjectId);

            context.IsActive = false;

            if (user != null)
            {
                if (_userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
                {
                    var security_stamp = subject.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "security_stamp").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (security_stamp != null)
                    {
                        var db_security_stamp = await _userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
                        if (db_security_stamp != security_stamp)
                            return;
                    }
                }

                context.IsActive =
                    !user.LockoutEnabled ||
                    !user.LockoutEnd.HasValue ||
                    user.LockoutEnd <= DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        private async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetClaimsFromUser(ApplicationUser user,ClaimsPrincipal subject)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, user.Id),
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.PreferredUserName, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName)

            };

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Name))
                claims.Add(new Claim("name", user.Name));

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.LastName))
                claims.Add(new Claim("last_name", user.LastName));
            claims.Add(new Claim(PermissionConstants.PackedPermissionClaimType,
               await _calcAllowedPermissions.CalcPermissionsForUserAsync(user.Id)));

               if (_userManager.SupportsUserEmail)
            {
                claims.AddRange(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, user.EmailConfirmed ? "true" : "false", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
                });
            }

            if (_userManager.SupportsUserPhoneNumber && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.PhoneNumber))
            {
                claims.AddRange(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.PhoneNumber, user.PhoneNumber),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.PhoneNumberVerified, user.PhoneNumberConfirmed ? "true" : "false", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
                });
            }

            return claims;
        }
    }
```

GetClaimsFromUser method is where you should add your claims.

Comment: Have you added Profile to allowed scopeslike first step?

Comment: Yes I have implemented the way you have told

Comment: I have to login just to give kudus, coz this saved my days of research. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was not passing the Subject claim.

```
public static List<TestUser> GetSampleUsers()
        {
            var subjectId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            return new List<TestUser>
            {
                new TestUser
                {
                    Username = "admin@local.com",
                    Password = "RockStar.1",

                    Claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "Admin "),
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, "Admin"),
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, "add min"),
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "admin@local.com"),
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, subjectId) --> This solve the issue
                    }
                }
            };
    }
```